# Comparing two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

I have a master table and a temp table that look something like:

- **things_temp**

  ```
  +----+--------+--------------+
  | id | number | current_time |
  +----+--------+--------------+
  |  1 |    456 | 9/16/2013    |
  |  2 |    123 | 9/16/2013    |
  +----+--------+--------------+
  ```
- **things_master**

  ```
  +----+--------+--------------+-----+
  | id | number | last_updated | old |
  +----+--------+--------------+-----+
  |  1 |    456 | 9/15/2013    |   0 |
  |  2 |    234 | 9/15/2013    |   0 |
  |  3 |    888 | 8/14/2012    |   1 |
  +----+--------+--------------+-----+
  ```

I need to iterate through the `things_temp` table and, if there exists the same `number` in `things_master` AND `old == 0`, update the `last_updated` to the `current_time`.

Otherwise, if both conditions above are not satisfied, simply add the record from `things_temp` to `things_master` with `last_updated` as `current_time` and `old = 0`.

Now, I could easily get the count of `things_temp` and check each one individually.  But there are something like 40,000 records in each table so I think that may be a bad idea.

I've been looking around and there are things like `UNION ALL`, `LEFT JOIN`, `INNER JOIN` that all seem like they may be a part of the solution, but I'm a bit lost.

Is there a better way to accomplish my task without iterating through each record of `things_temp` and searching through `things_master`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do this in one statement by abusing `replace into`, but it's probably clearer to do it in two steps. Other databases support `merge` which is designed for this sort of thing.

```
start transaction;

-- update any matching numbers with the data from thing_temp
update 
    things_master m 
        inner join 
    things_temp t
        on m.number = t.number
set
    m.last_updated = t.`current_time`
where
    m.old = 0;

-- add any missing numbers
insert into 
    things_master (number, last_updated, old)
Select
    number, `current_time`, 0
From
    things_temp t
Where
    not exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            things_master m
        where
            t.number = m.number and
            m.old = 0
    );

commit transaction;
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Given the number of records in each table (about 40k each) - do you have a sense on the time factor?  Should I be indexing the number column in each table?

Comment: Yes, you should be indexing number on both tables. I wouldn't expect it to take too long.